# removing only SOME <span> tags in HTML

Tags: html, code-cleanup

An annoying software bug has caused some of our HTML to be littered with literally *thousands* of empty  tags. For instance, one line should look like this:

```
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
<span><span><span><span><span><p>Hello, world!</p></span></span></span></span></span>
```

Normally I would do a simple find/replace to remove the `<span>` tags, but *some* of those tags actually serve a purpose. What regex could I run against the HTML to remove these superfluous tags? Or is there another tool I could use?

EDIT: To clarify, some `span` tags actually serve a purpose, and we'd need to keep those, such as:

```
<span style="border-top: 1px solid black">Hello, world!</span>
```

Comment: you can remove the unwanted tags using with jquery or javascript

Comment: Certainly regex isn't the answer here.

Comment: $('#divhtml').find('span').remove() use this on document load

Comment: which tag exactly you need to delete ,Although we can remove all span tag with <(?!/?span\\b)[^>]*>

Comment: @PardeepPathania edited for clarity.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser so what is? :-(